# Wrong value for form in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a privacy function.If `public = 1`, the post is public, else if is 0, the post is private.I have this toggle :

```
<label class="toggle" style="right: 185px">{{ Form::checkbox('public') }}<i class="no-rounded privancy"></i></label>
```

The toggle is set on public by default, but at submit, in database I receive `NULL` in column `public`. If I press the button on private, in database I Receive `1`, and 1 is for PUBLIC. How it's working?How can I make this working because I need this.

Comment: Unchecked checkbox value will not be submitted after submitting the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at code that generates the checkbox, you'll see it can take up to 4 arguments, the third being whether or not it is checked by default, and what the value is. The value is 1 by default. So when you check it, it will return 1.

```
public static function checkbox($name, $value = 1, $checked = null, $options = array())
{
    return \Collective\Html\FormBuilder::checkbox($name, $value, $checked, $options);
}
```

Just change your form to value of 2 to return 2 when checked.

```
Form::checkbox('public', 2)
```

And as pointed out in your comments, an unchecked checkbox will not be submitted so you will have to check in the controller when you save.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$public = 0; // set default value as `0` indicating post is not public
if(isset($_POST['public'])) {
   $public = 1; // if the public checkbox is checked while sumitting the form then set value as `1`
}
```

Use the `$public` value to store/update in the database.

Comment: with this I receive `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'public' cannot be null`

Comment: Can you share the php code which inserts the data in the database